# Why $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_n$ for $n\geq8$, where $a_{n+1}$ is the second smallest number that is not the sum of any earlier terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of numbers defined as $a_0=0$ and $a_{n+1}$ for $n\geq0$ is the second smallest number that is greater than $a_n$ and is not the sum of any earlier distinct terms.

This sequence should be {0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 18, 33, 38, 86, 162, 284, 522, 928, 1688, 3022, 5470, 9826, 17744, 31926, 57588, 103696, 186946, 336750, 606946, 1093500, 1970642, 3550696, 6398480, 11529230, 20775494, 37435474, 67457232, 121552686, 219031676, 394679816, 711190482, 1281518438, 2309219586, 4161065980, 7497986714...}.

Edit:
For example, $a_4=10$ because from $0,2,4,7$, we can get $0,2,4,6(=2+4),7,9(=2+7),11(=4+7),13(=2+4+7)$. So, *the numbers that is not the sum of any earlier distinct terms* are $1,3,5,8,10,12,14,15,\ldots$, and the second smallest number that is bigger than $a_3=7$ is $a_4=10$.

Edit 2: On the other hand, for instance, if we define the number sequence $\{a_n\}$ as *the first smallest number*, we get 0,1,2,4,8,16,32,64,...

Using Wolfram Alpha and some other tools, I noticed that $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ holds for $n=5,n\geq8$ and at least $n<40$. It seems strange to me that this relation holds only for n greater than 4, so I changed the first terms to see what relation holds, then all the ones I've tried satisfied $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ or $a_{n+12}=31a_{n+6}-4a_{n}$ except for the first few terms.
I would like to know why these relations hold and why they don't hold for the first few terms.

Examples of $\{a_n\}$: (Edit 3: I checked up to $n<10000$)

- $a_0=0$:
  $\{a_n\}={0,2,4,7,10,18,33,38,86,162,284,522,928,\cdots}$
  $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ for $n=5,n\geq8$
- $a_0=1$:
  $\{a_n\}={1,3,6,11,16,29,53,61,138,260,456,838,1490,\cdots}$
  $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ for $n=0,5,n\geq8$
- $a_0=2$:
  $\{a_n\}={2,4,7,10,18,33,38,86,162,284,522,928,1688,\cdots}$
  $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ for $n=4,n\geq7$
- $a_0=3$:
  $\{a_n\}={3,5,7,11,17,34,64,73,167,313,548,1007,1790,\cdots}$
  $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ for $n=5,n\geq8$
- $a_0=0,a_1=1$:
  $\{a_n\}={0,1,3,6,11,16,29,53,61,138,260,456,838,1490,\cdots}$
  $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ for $n=1,6,n\geq9$
- $a_0=2,a_1=3$:
  $\{a_n\}={2,3,6,10,17,31,55,79,158,299,519,959,1698,2437,\cdots}$
  $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_{n}$ for $n=0,\ 2,3,5,\ 8,9,11,\ 14,15,17,\ 20,21,23,\ 26,27,29\ldots$
  $a_{n+12}=31a_{n+6}-4a_{n}$ for $n\geq1$

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRNb9swDL3nV7DNxW6UwLLTtQumHDZg5wHbzRAKJ1YSYYrsyUrrYdtvzyQqdj7a7iOGHfrJ5HuUSNbf7abS2X4vt3VlLCxkI5Z2UIoVvBdrqT/bworICrNtZko2Np4NAMqa5R8L1Qh@EzW7bViORzTGtTzh7IvZCfeyqgxYkBpCAIcETHrMiEdhGlFGptBrx0GU0FFZx3EcPsRYkv9k/m9sOQafFHUtdBkhveczwu6MhlyGwKT0oYXebYXxyl08kCvQlYWSDzCvDxux/BqtpGnsRV5DUDPnuXCy4GkjlxtYFtq7LgSItjaicXKhaKAAlzZUK6jsRpiQHfq7n3L5E5VTTiaTiTMK/alqxu41Kh503AEcoDNHlPdmil5@aZx61PlBoUtQhVkLgxRs/gqFc8Bde8Z5hl4QhwCvkiVAIYUMpnALb@AO7uEt0OQ5lr6AZQHzcfIFtNDd1eHZ37yFf7kAZqDYD0oyckvuCU0ITQmd/kKh8@fXf5N6ArdfzEXG/WHTV7Uv3B2utn/@LfSp9ltC70makDQlKWaAJcSORekgxU468Ljii14z3yvnWJCsRWujrhfa815Q2Art/Ojnj9z7umJXAvQ7l3qShO4LFcIovoR1hOZIrfoeVV1HYv2EGQC4jV3BISBZmCyT8Pdg5HpjIxWqbuyrFD/T4kmxvB05AHPADFQuZzyE@eMEQToS5B2HiEtZ5efkSqwCtwzU/Ip19gyG4ttOPhYujAVbwTX6h0UcI17Q9SG2T7@u6kjGR3Vq4o7Ab4jPJeC4190@9bkOOnVOcDjFOZueqO5P6IodzJSP0puDnfHxwZryWS@nNlLbSJOepCP3KpMADS84aRb8h5esGe3I7vh42tk04/33LxAOX2DUvo4GYe660RXv978B) (Shows $n,a_n$ which doesn't satisfy $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}$ for $a_n=0,\ n<1000$)

Comment: Please explain, with the **difficult-to-understand-definition** in the title, how in particular, you obtain $a_1=2$, $a_2=4$... Otherwise, I am afraid you will have no answer...

Comment: Perhaps look into  (the proof of) Zeckendorf's theorem?

Comment: Also, the linear recurrences suggest exponential growth, which would mean that from some point on, the sum of the first $n$ terms is strictly less that the $(n+1)$'th term. This then would mean that the representation of an integer as a sum of distinct elements of the sequence is unique if it exists, for all 'representable' integers above a certain bound

Comment: @Mastrem, Per [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=roots+of+x%5E3+-+x%5E2+-2x%2B1+%3D+0), the characteristic polynomial has roots $$\frac 13\left(1-\frac {7\alpha}{\beta} - \bar\alpha\beta\right),\frac 13\left(1-\frac {7\bar\alpha}{\beta} - \alpha\beta\right),\frac13\left(1+\frac 7{\beta} + \beta\right)$$where $\alpha = \frac{1+i\sqrt 3}2, \beta = \sqrt[3]{\frac 72(-1+i3\sqrt 3)}$. Or approximately $-1.24698, 0.44504, 1.8019$. Since all of theses have magnitude $< 2$, they will never outstrip the sums of earlier terms.

Comment: It is not at all strange for an integer sequence to only satisfy a recursion formula after a number of leading terms. Obviously anyone can create artificial examples, but I've seen several "naturally occurring" examples like yours. In your case it only fails (assuming you are correct about holding for higher numbers) on the smallest possible case where the recursion formula is defined.

Comment: The [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+2%2C+4%2C+7%2C+10%2C+18%2C+33%2C+38%2C+86%2C+162%2C+284%2C+522%2C+928&sort=&language=english&go=Search) does not recognize this sequence, even when truncated. How sure are you that those values are correct? You might want to add the sequence to OEIS.

Comment: Although I checked the first few terms by hand, I've only calculated one method with Python and haven't confirmed it, so I'm not sure. Double-checking is welcome. And I am not so familiar with OEIS, it would be nice if someone could add it to the OEIS.

Comment: There are some (minor) inaccuracies: you first say that for the recurrence to hold it must be $n > 4$ and afterwards you say it must be $n = 5$ or $n \ge 8$, while it actually fails at $n = 5$, $n = 9$ and $n = 10$. I have checked it just up to $n = 17$.

Comment: @BillyJoe Could you please share what values you obtained? The values I wrote above hold it for $n=5,n\geq8$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I thought about $a_n = ...$ instead of $a_{n+3} = ...$. I have your same values. But still you should edit the first $n > 4$ and make it equal to the second condition below $n = 5, n \ge 8$.

Comment: Two mistakes I noticed : in your enumeration of the main sequence, you forgot the $15$ between the $10$ and the $18$. Also, the recurrence is $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}-a_n$, not $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}-a_n$.

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy $15$ is the first number that cannot be expressed as sum of lower $a_n$ values, but we seek the second one. Also, check again the recurrence carefully.

Comment: @BillyJoe I see my mistake now, the sequence in the OP is about the sum of an ARBITRARY number of distinct earlier terms, not just two.

Comment: According to [this page](http://www.lmfdb.org/NumberField/3.3.49.1), the characteristic polynomial of the recurrence is the cubic polynomial with Galois group $C_3$ with the smallest absolute discriminant. Maybe the "smallest discriminant" property is somehow related to "second smallest number" from the definition.

Comment: As a remark: I left out the "and greater than $a_n$" condition the first time I coded this, and the resulting sequence is $0$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $8$, $16$, $32$, ... in other words, after a certain point, it is just powers of $2$.

Comment: A second remark: Writing $\zeta$ for a primitive $7$-th root of unity, the roots of the characteristic polynomial $x^3-x^2-2x+1$ are $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$,  $\zeta^2+\zeta^{-2}$ and  $\zeta^3+\zeta^{-3}$.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: The roots of  $^3−^2−2+1$ are precisely $\xi+\xi^{-1},\xi^3+\xi^{-3},\xi^5+\xi^{-5}$ with a primitive 14-th root of unity $\xi$.

Comment: Oh, did I have a sign error? We have $\xi = - \zeta$ (if we have chosen appropriate roots of unity) and $\zeta^{\pm 2} = \zeta^{\mp 5}$, so your formulas are the same as mine up to sign. @Helmut

Comment: How did you check up to $n=10000$? Certainly you didn't actually enumerate all integers from 1 up to $a_{10000}\approx 1.8^{10000}$.

Comment: There are only a few (about $2n$) numbers that cannot be expressed as the sum of other terms, so I focused on those. I added the URL to the code on Try It Online.

Comment: Interesting. It is not at all obvious that this should be the case.

Comment: I added this sequence to [OEIS A343328](https://oeis.org/A343328).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first part, it is shown that the recursion $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ follows under a certain condition. In the second part, it is shown that the condition is satisfied for $n\geq9$ if $a_0=0$. The other initial conditions will be treated later.
Consider besides the sequence $a_n$, $n\geq0$, the increasing sequences $b_n$ of those numbers that cannot be written as sums of distinct $a_n$ and the sequence $c_n=a_0+...+a_n$. It is also essential to introduce the sets $B^{(n)}\subset\{0,...,c_n-1\}$ of those numbers that cannot be written as sums of distinct $a_i$ with $0\leq i\leq n$.
Clearly, a number $x$ can be written as a sum of certain distinct $a_i$ with $0\leq i\leq n$ if and only if $c_n-x$ can: The summation for $c_n-x$ is taken over the indices that do not appear in the summation for $x$. This means that $t\in B^{(n)}$ if and only if $c_n-t\in B^{(n)}$. $B^{(n)}$ is updated recursively with $a_n$ if we want to determine $a_n$ for large $n$.
I. Assume that for a certain $n$ the elements of $B^{(n)}$ between $b_{n-3}$ and $2a_n$ are exactly
$$b_{n-3},b_{n-2},b_{n-1},c_n-b_{n-1},c_n-b_{n-2},2a_n$$
and that $2a_n=c_n-b_{n-3}$. Furthermore assume that $b_{n-3} < b_{n-2} < b_{n-1}< a_n<c_n-b_{n-1}$. This might seem to be a lot of assumptions, but they are, for example, satisfied for $a_0=0$ and $n=9,10,11,12$.
Then $c_n-b_{n-2}$ is the second smallest number larger than $a_n$ that cannot be written as a sum of distinct integers in ${a_0,...,a_n}$ and we obtain $a_{n+1}=c_n-b_{n-2}$. As now $c_n-b_{n-1}<a_{n+1}$ cannot be written as a sum of *any* distinct elements of the whole sequence $a_k$, we also have $b_n=c_{n}-b_{n-1}$. Observe that $b_{n-1}<a_n<b_n$. Finally, by definition, $c_{n+1}=c_n+a_{n+1}$ and we also obtain $a_{n+1}<c_{n+1}-b_n$ because this is equivalent to $c_n>b_n$ which is true by $b_n=c_n-b_{n-1}$. Observe that $a_{n+1}=c_n-b_{n-2}$ implies that $2a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}-b_{n-2}$.
To complete the recursion, we must show that the elements of $B^{(n+1)}$ between $b_{n-2}$ and $2a_{n+1}$ are exactly
$$b_{n-2},b_{n-1},b_{n},c_{n+1}-b_{n},c_{n+1}-b_{n-1},2a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}-b_{n-2}.$$
How is $B^{(n+1)}$ obtained from $B^{(n)}$?
a) The elements of the form $x+a_{n+1}$ with $x\in B^{(n)}$  for which $x+a_{n+1}>c_n$ are added to $B^{(n)}$ because they cannot be sums of distinct elements of $\{a_0,...,a_{n+1}\}$.
b) $a_{n+1}$ and the elements $y$ of $B^{(n)}$ such that $y-a_{n+1}$ is not in $B^{(n)}$ are removed from the resulting set because $y-a_{n+1}$ is a sum of distinct elements of
$\{a_0,...,a_{n}\}$ if it is not in $B^{(n)}$.
From these relations we now want to deduce that the elements of $B^{(n+1)}$ between $b_{n-2}$ and $2a_{n+1}$ are exactly
$$b_{n-2},b_{n-1},b_{n},c_{n+1}-b_{n},c_{n+1}-b_{n-1},2a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}-b_{n-2}.$$
*At this point, we introduce the additional condition that $b_{n-4}<b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}<b_{n-3}$.*
First, this implies that $b_0+a_{n+1},...,b_{n-4}+a_{n+1}$ are between $a_{n+1}$ and $2a_n$ because $b_{n-4}+a_{n+1}<2a_n$ is equivalent to $b_{n-4}+c_n-b_{n-2}<c_n-b_{n-3}$ and therefore to $b_{n-4}<b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}$. As by assumption, there are no elements of $B^{(n)}$ between $a_{n+1}$ and $2a_n$, all these elements are sums of distinct elements of $\{a_0,...a_n\}$. (If $b_0=0$ then $b_0+a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}$ has not to be considered here.) Hence they are not in $B^{(n+1)}$ either. Hence also their "complements" $c_n-b_0-a_{n+1},...,c_n-b_{n-4}-a_{n+1}$ are not in $B^{(n)}$, so
$c_n-b_0,...,c_n-b_{n-4}$, i.e. the elements of $B^{(n)}$ above $2a_n=c_n-b_{n-3}$ are not in $B^{(n+1)}$. By construction, $b_n=c_n-b_{n-1}$ remains in $B^{(n+1)}$, but $a_{n+1}=c_n-b_{n-2}$ is not in that set. What about $2a_n$?
We have $2a_n-a_{n+1}=c_n-b_{n-3}-(c_n-b_{n-2})=b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}$ and therefore, by the above additional condition, it is not in $B^{(n)}$ and hence $2a_n$ is not in $B^{(n+1)}$. Finally, we must treat $b_j+a_{n+1}$, $j=n-3,...,n$ and $2a_{n+1}$.
The latter is in $B^{(n+1)}$, because by construction $a_{n+1}$ is in $B^{(n)}$.
We have $b_{n-3}+a_{n+1}$ (which is smaller than $c_n$) not in $B^{(n)}$, because $c_n-b_{n-3}-a_{n+1}=b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}$ is not. Hence it is also not in $B^{(n+1)}$.
$b_{n-2}+a_{n+1}=c_n$ is not in $B^{(n)}$. $b_{n-1}+a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}-b_n$ is in $B^{(n+1)}$ and so is $b_{n}+a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}-b_{n-1}$. This proves that the elements of $B^{(n+1)}$ between $b_{n-2}$ and $2a_{n+1}$ are the ones listed above and completes the recursive step.
This shows that if the assumptions from the beginning for a certain $n=n_0$ are satisfied and if the additional condition holds for all $n\geq n_0$ then we have for all $n\geq n_0$
$$b_n=c_n-b_{n-1},\ a_{n+1}=c_n-b_{n-2},\ c_{n+1}=c_n+a_{n+1}.$$
Eliminating $a_{n+1}$ from these relations, we find $c_n=b_n+b_{n-1}$ and $c_{n+1}=2c_n-b_{n-2}$. Eliminating now $c_n$, we find $b_{n+1}=b_n+2b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$.
So the sequence $b_n$ satisfies the recursion we want. This carries over to the sequence $c_n$ because $c_n=b_n+b_{n-1}$ and to the sequence $a_n$ because
$a_n=c_n-c_{n-1}$. This completes the first part.
II. The last example shows that there can be no general proof (i.e. for all initial conditions) that after a while, the sequence $a_n$ will satisfy the recursion $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}$. For the initial condition of the original sequence ($a_0=0$) it is shown here using finitely many computations that $a_n$ does satisfy the recursion for $n\geq9$.
We calculate the sequences $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ ( see part I for their definitions) up to $n=13$. I used pari/gp, but in pricinple, it could be done by hand if one uses the updating procedure for $B^{(n)}$ from part I. It turns out that $2a_n-a_{n+1}$ is always a sum of distinct integers in $\{a_0,...,a_n\}$ except for $n=5$. The results for $n=6,...,13$ are
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline
n& 6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13\\\hline
a_n& 33& 38&  86& 162& 284& 522& 928& 1688\\\hline
b_n& 36& 76& 122& 238& 406& 760& 1334& 2448\\\hline
c_n& 74&112& 198& 360& 644& 1166& 2094& 3782\\\hline
b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}&  -5& 14& 10& 40& 46& 116& 168& 354\\\hline
2b_{n-1}-b_n& 16& -4& 30& 6& 70& 52& 186& 220\\\hline
\delta_n& -12& 3& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\\hline
\varepsilon_n& 2&-21& 0&33& -12& 0&0& 0\\\hline
\end{array}$$
Here $\delta_n=b_n-b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}$, $\varepsilon_n=a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$. We list $b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$ and $2b_{n-1}-b_n$, because the additional condition necessary for the first part is $b_{n-4}<b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}<b_{n-3}$.
For $n_0=13$, we also list the elements of $B^{(n_0)}$ between $b_{n_0-3}$ and
$2a_{n_0}$:
$$406, 760, 1334, 2448, 3022, 3376.$$
They are $b_{n_0-3},b_{n_0-2},b_{n_0-1},c_{n_0}-b_{n_0-1},c_{n_0}-b_{n_0-2},2a_{n_0}$ as needed in the beginning of part I.
We have $2a_{n_0}=c_{n_0}-b_{n_0-3}$ and the elements are ordered as needed.
Finally, we have $b_{n_0-4}<b_{n_0-2}-b_{n_0-3}<b_{n_0-3}$, i.e. the additional condition necessary for part I to work because $b_{n_0-2}-b_{n_0-3}-b_{n_0-4}>0$ and $2b_{n_0-3}-b_{n_0-2}>0$. All this can be checked in the above table.
Part I shows that then all the conditions (except maybe the last inequalities) are also satisfied for $n=n_0+1=14$ instead of $n_0$ and that
$$(1)\ \ \ b_{n}=c_{n}-b_{n-1},\ a_{n+1}=c_{n}-b_{n-2},\ c_{n+1}=c_{n}+a_{n+1}$$
for $n=n_0$.
The table shows that we also have $b_{n_0-3}<b_{n_0-1}-b_{n_0-2}<b_{n_0-2}$. Therefore, we can also proceed to $n=n_0+2$ and to $n=n_0+3$ and all the conditions hold, except maybe the inequalities. We have seen at the end of part I, that the relations (1) for $n_0$ and $n_0+1$ imply that the sequence $b_n$ satisfies the recursion
$$(2)\ \ \ \ x_{n+1}=x_n+2x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}$$
for $n=n_0$.
Hence this is already the case for $b_n$,  $n=n_0$ and $n_0+1$.  We had checked it beforehand for $n=7,...,n=n_0-1$ in the table. As a consequence, the sequences $d_n=b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$ and $e_n=2b_{n-1}-b_n$ sastisfy the recursion (2) already for $n=9,...,n=n_0+1$.
Now observe that any sequence solution of (2) such that $0<x_{k-2}<x_{k-1}<x_{k}$ for a certain $k$ also satisfies $x_k<x_{k+1}$ because $x_{k+1}-x_k=2x_{k-1}-x_{k-2}>0$. Hence  $0<x_{k-1}<x_{k}<x_{k+1}$. Now as seen above, $d_n$ and $e_n$ satisfy the recursion for $n=n_0$ and $n=n_0+1$ and in the table, we see that $0<d_{n_0-2}<d_{n_0-1}<d_{n_0}$ and $0<e_{n_0-2}<e_{n_0-1}<e_{n_0}$. The choice of $n_0$ is motivated by this fact. Hence first, $0<d_{n_0-1}<d_{n_0}<d_{n_0+1}$ and then $0<d_{n_0}<d_{n_0+1}<d_{n_0+2}$ and similarly, $0<e_{n_0}<e_{n_0+1}<e_{n_0+2}$. In particular, $d_{n_0+1},d_{n_0+2},e_{n_0+1},e_{n_0+2}$ are positive.
This allows to proceed to higher and higher $n$: All conditions necessary for
part I to work are always satisfied. Therefore, the recursion (2) for $b_n$
is satisfied for **all** $n\geq 7$! Since $c_n=b_n+b_{n-1}$ and $a_n=c_n-c_{n-1}$ at least for $n\geq n_0$, the recursion (2) holds for $a_n$ and all $n\geq n_0+2$, at least. The table and the calculations for $n=13,14$ mentioned above, which yield $a_{14},a_{15}$, show that it is actually true for $n\geq10$.
III. The same method works for all the examples, except of course, the last one. The third and
fifth example are actually the same as the first and second, respectively, except for the first
term.

In the second example($a_0=1$), we proceed as for the first one (see I. and II.). I just put the
results of the calculations for $n=6,...,13$
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline
n&6& 7& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13\\\hline
a_n& 53& 61& 138& 260& 456& 838& 1490& 2710\\\hline
b_n& 58& 122& 196& 382& 652& 1220& 2142& 3930\\\hline
c_n& 119& 180& 318& 578& 1034& 1872& 3362& 6072\\\hline
b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}& -8& 22& 16& 64& 74& 186& 270& 568\\\hline
2b_{n-1}-b_n& 26& -6& 48& 10& 112& 84& 298& 354\\\hline
\delta_n& -19& 4& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\\hline
\varepsilon_n& 3& -34& 0& 53& -19& 0& 0& 0\\\hline
\end{array}$$
Here again $\delta_n=b_n-b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}+b_{n-3}$,
$\varepsilon_n=a_n-a_{n-1}-2a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ and we list $b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$ and $2b_{n-1}-b_n$,
because the additional condition necessary is $b_{n-4}<b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}<b_{n-3}$.
For $n_0=13$, we also list the elements of $B^{(n_0)}$ between $b_{n_0-3}$ and
$2a_{n_0}$:
$$652, 1220, 2142, 3930, 4852, 5420.$$
They are $b_{n_0-3},b_{n_0-2},b_{n_0-1},c_{n_0}-b_{n_0-1},c_{n_0}-b_{n_0-2},2a_{n_0}$ as in part I.
The remaining considerations are as for the first example.

Also in the fourth example ($a_0=3$), we proceed as for the first one. Here, we have to calculate
until $n=15$ in order to have three subsequent increasing values for $b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}$ and
$2b_{n-1}-b_n$. The resulte for $n=8,...,15$ are
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline
n& 8& 9& 10& 11& 12& 13& 14& 15\\\hline
a_n& 167& 313& 548& 1007& 1790& 3256& 5829& 10551\\\hline
b_n& 235& 459& 783& 1466& 2573& 4722& 8402& 15273\\\hline
c_n& 381& 694& 1242& 2249& 4039& 7295& 13124& 23675\\\hline
b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}& -9& 31& 21& 78& 89& 224& 324& 683\\\hline
2b_{n-1}-b_n& 26& -10& 57& 11& 135& 100& 359& 424\\\hline
\delta_n& -26& 14& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\\hline
\varepsilon_n& 0& 64& -26& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\\hline
\end{array}$$
Again for $n_0=15$, we list the elements of $B^{(n_0)}$ between $b_{n_0-3}$ and
$2a_{n_0}$:
$$2573, 4722, 8402, 15273, 18953, 21102.$$
The rest is as for the above example and the first example.
Observe that here, the indices of the sequence $b_n$ have been
shifted to have $b_{n-1}<a_n<b_n$.

IV. The last example is quite  different. Every sixth value of $n$, we have that $2a_n-a_{n+1}$
is in $B^{(n)}$, i.e. not a sum of distinct elements of $\{a_0,...,a_n\}$.
Unfortunately the condition necessary for part I to work is also not satisfied for certain of the remaining
$5/6$-th of the steps as we will see. This requires modifications of the considerations
of part I.
First, we calculate up to $n=7$:
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}\hline
n&0& 1& 2& 3& 4& 5& 6& 7\\\hline
a_n&2& 3& 6& 10& 17& 31& 55& 79\\\hline
b_n&1& 4& 7& 14& 24& 45& 62& 141\\\hline
c_n& 2& 5& 11& 21& 38& 69& 124& 203\\\hline
b_n-b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}&*& *& 2& 3& 3& 7& -7& 34\\\hline
2b_{n-1}-b_n&*& -2& 1& 0& 4& 3& 28& -17\\\hline
\end{array}$$
Here we have for convenience omitted 0 from the sets $B^{(n)}$ and start with $b_0=1$.
Now we proceed by induction, but a complicated one.
We summarize the situation at $n=7$ with $x=b_6=62$ and $y=b_5=45$ as parameters.
We perform six steps (five of them almost as in part I) and show that we arrive at the same situation
except for other values of $x,y$.
Then by induction, we obtain that the complete sequences $a_n,b_n,c_n$ are obtained by repeting
these six steps. The recursion
$a_{n+12}=31a_{n+6}-4a_n$ follows.
We suppose that for some $n$ the numbers in $B^{(n)}$ between $b_{n-3}$ and $2a_n$ are
$$b_{n-3},b_{n-2}=y,b_{n-1}=x, 3x-y,2a_n.$$
We also suppose that $a_n=2x-y$ and $c_n=4x-y$. If we assume $b_{n-3}<y$ then
the list is in ascending order because of $y<x$. In the sequel, the expressions of all quantities
in terms of $x,y$ allow to compare them just using $y<x$. These details are omitted. Finally, we assume that
$b_{n-4}<b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}<b_{n-3}$ and that $b_{n-4}<b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}<b_{n-3}$.
We conclude that $2a_n=c_n-b_{n-2}$. So the situation is different from that in the beginning
of part I. We also conclude that $c_{n-1}=c_n-a_n=2x$.
Observe that this situation is given for $n=7$ as can be verified in the above table.

1. As in part I, we find $b_n=3x-y$ and $a_{n+1}=2a_n=4x-2y,$ hence $c_{n+1}=8x-3y.$
   As in part I, we update $B^{(n)}$. The numbers $b_j+a_{n+1}$, $j=0,...,n-4$, are not in $B^{(n)}$,
   because their complements are $c_{n}-b_j-a_{n+1}=b_{n-2}-b_j$ and hence between
   $b_{n-2}-b_{n-4}>b_{n-3}$ and $b_{n-2}$. $b_{n-3}+a_{n+1}$ is not in $B^{(n)}$ because its
   complement $c_{n}-b_{n-3}-a_{n+1}=b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}$ is not. This implies that
   $b_j+a_{n+1}$, $j=0,...,n-3$, are not in $B^{(n+1)}$. The above fact that $c_{n}-b_j-a_{n+1}$
   $j=0,...,n-3$, is not in $B^{(n)}$ also implies that the corresponding $c_n-b_j$
   are not in $B^{(n+1)}$. Again, $b_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n+1}$ is in $B^{(n+1)}$, but $a_{n+1}$ is removed.
   $b_{n-2}+a_{n+1}=4x-y=c_n$ is not in $B^{(n+1)}$, but
   $b_{n-1}+a_{n+1}=5x-2y=c_{n+1}-b_n$ and $b_{n}+a_{n+1}=7x-3y=c_{n+1}-b_{n-1}$ are in $B^{(n)}$ and
   so is $2a_{n+1}=8x-4y$.
   The elements of $B^{(n+1)}$ between $b_{n-2}$ and $2a_{n+1}$ are now
   $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   b_{n-2}&b_{n-1}&b_{n}&c_{n+1}-b_n&c_{n+1}-b_{n-1}&2a_{n+1}\\\hline
   y&x&3x-y&5x-2y&7x-3y&8x-4y
   \end{array}.$$
   We have $c_{n+1}=8x-3y$ and hence $2a_{n+1}=c_{n+1}-b_{n-2}$.
   We had assumed that $b_{n-4}<b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}<b_{n-3}$.
2. Before the beginning of the second step, the situation is therefore as before the
   step in part I, except that  $b_{n-4}<b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}<b_{n-3}$ here.
   We proceed (almost) as in part I or in the above first step, except that
   $b_{n-3}+a_{n+2}$ has to be treated apart. We omit the details. We arrive at
   the following situation before step 3.
   The elements of $B^{(n+2)}$ between $b_{n-1}$ and $2a_{n+2}$, $a_{n+2}=7x-3y$ are now
   $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   b_{n-1}&b_{n}&b_{n+1}&c_{n+2}-b_{n+1}&c_{n+2}-b_{n}&2a_{n+2}\\\hline
   x&3x-y&5x-2y&10x-4y&12x-5y&14x-6y
   \end{array}.$$
   We have $c_{n+2}=15x-6y$ and hence $2a_{n+2}=c_{n+2}-b_{n-1}$.
   Observe that $c_{n+2}=3b_{n+1}$ and hence $c_{n+2}-b_{n+1}=2b_{n+1}$! This will be crucial later.
   Here we have that $b_n-b_{n-1}=2x-y>x=b_{n-1}$.
3. Before the beginning of the third step, the situation is therefore as before the
   step in part I, except that  $b_{n}-b_{n-1}>b_{n-1}$ here.
   We proceed (almost) as in part I or in the above steps. The treatment of $b_j+a_{n+3}$ is
   even simpler than before. We omit the details. We arrive at
   the following situation before step 4 which is as before the step in part I.
   The elements of $B^{(n+3)}$ between $b_{n}$ and $2a_{n+3}$, $a_{n+3}=c_{n+2}-b_{n}=12x-5y$,
   are now with $c_{n+3}=27x-11y=2a_{n+3}+b_{n}$:
   $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   b_{n}&b_{n+1}&b_{n+2}&c_{n+3}-b_{n+2}&c_{n+3}-b_{n+1}&2a_{n+3}\\\hline
   3x-y&5x-2y&10x-4y&17x-7y&22x-9y&24x-10y
   \end{array}.$$
   We have $b_{n+1}-b_{n}=2x-y$ again and this has been seen to be between $b_{n-1}$ and $b_n$.
4. So we can proceed as in part I (details omitted). We arrive at the following situation before
   step 5:
   The elements of $B^{(n+4)}$ between $b_{n+1}$ and $2a_{n+4}$, $a_{n+4}=c_{n+3}-b_{n+1}=22x-9y$,
   are now with $c_{n+4}=49x-20y=2a_{n+4}+b_{n+1}$:
   $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   b_{n+1}&b_{n+2}&b_{n+3}&c_{n+4}-b_{n+3}&c_{n+4}-b_{n+2}&2a_{n+4}\\\hline
   5x-2y&10x-4y&17x-7y&32x-13y&39x-16y&44x-18y
   \end{array}.$$
   Observe that now $b_{n+2}=2b_{n+1}$ and the situation is different from all the other steps.
5. We find as before $b_{n+4}=c_{n+4}-b_{n+3}=32x-13y$ and
   $a_{n+5}=c_{n+4}-b_{n+2}=39x-16y$, so that
   $c_{n+5}=88x-36y$. By chance, $c_{n+5}=4a_{n+4}$.
   The numbers $b_j+a_{n+5}$, $j=1,...,n$, are not in
   $B^{(n+4)}$, because their complements $c_{n+4}-b_j-a_{n+5}=b_{n+2}-b_j$ are
   between $b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}=b_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+2}$ and hence not in $B^{(n+4)}$.
   Therefore  $b_j+a_{n+5}$, $j=1,...,n$ are also not in $B^{(n+5)}$.
   Contrary to all other steps, $b_{n+1}+a_{n+5}$ is in $B^{(n+4)}$ and thus also in
   $B^{(n+5)}$, because it complement $b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}=b_{n+1}$ is in $B^{(n+4)}$.
   Observe that $b_{n+1}+a_{n+5}=2a_{n+4}$. As before, $c_{n+4}-b_j$, $j=1,...,n$,
   are not in $B^{(n+5)}$. We just saw that $c_{n+4}-b_{n+1}=2a_{n+4}$ is in
   $B^{(n+5)}$. $b_{n+2}+a_{n+5}=c_{n+4}$ is not in $B^{(n+5)}$.
   $b_{n+3}+a_{n+5}=c_{n+5}-b_{n+4}$ and $b_{n+4}+a_{n+5}=c_{n+5}-b_{n+3}$ are
   in $B^{(n+5)}$ as is $2a_{n+5}$.
   The elements of $B^{(n+5)}$ between $b_{n+2}$ and
   $2a_{n+5}$, $a_{n+5}=c_{n+4}-b_{n+2}=39x-16y$,
   are now with $c_{n+5}=88x-36y=2a_{n+5}+b_{n+2}$:
   $$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
   b_{n+2}&b_{n+3}&b_{n+4}&2a_{n+4}&c_{n+5}-b_{n+4}&c_{n+5}-b_{n+3}&2a_{n+5}\\\hline
   10x-4y&17x-7y&32x-13y&44x-18y&56x-23y&71x-29y&78x-32y
   \end{array}.$$
   We will use that $b_{n+4}-b_{n+3}=15x-6y$ between $b_{n+2}$ and $b_{n+3}$.
6. This final step is different because of the additional element $2a_{n+4}$ in
   $B^{(n+5)}$ between $b_{n+2}$ and $2 a_{n+5}$.
   We find  $b_{n+5}=2a_{n+4}=44x-18y$ and $a_{n+6}=c_{n+5}-b_{n+4}=56x-23y$
   so that $c_{n+6}=144y-59y$.
   Updating $B^{(n+5)}$, the elements $b_j+a_{n+6}$, $j=1,...,n+2$,
   are not in $B^{(n+5)}$ because their complements
   $c_{n+5}-b_j-a_{n+6}=b_{n+4}-b_j$ are between $b_{n+4}-b_{n+2}>b_{n+3}$ and
   $b_{n+4}$.
   Hence they are also not in $B^{(n+6)}$. For $j=n+3$, we find the complement
   $b_{n+4}-b_{n+3}\in]b_{n+2},b_{n+3}[$. Therefore $b_{n+3}+a_{n+6}$ is also not in
   $B^{(n+6)}$. $b_{n+4}+a_{n+6}=c_{n+5}$ is not in $B^{(n+6)}$.
   $2a_{n+4}+a_{n+6}=100x-41y=c_{n+6}-b_{n+5}$ is in $B^{(n+6)}$ and so is
   $2a_{n+6}$.
   $c_{n+5}-b_{n+3}$ is removed, because $c_{n+5}-b_{n+3}-a_{n+6}=15x-6y$ is
   between $b_{n+2}$ and $b_{n+3}$ and hence not in $B^{(n+5)}$.
   $2a_{n+5}$ is removed, because
   $2a_{n+5}-a_{n+6}=c_{n+5}-b_{n+2}-(c_{n+5}-b_{n+4})=b_{n+4}-b_{n+2}$ is between
   $b_{n+3}$ and $b_{n+4}$ and hence not in $B^{(n+5)}$.

As a result after six steps,
the elements of $B^{(n+6)}$ between $b_{n+3}$ and $2a_{n+6}$,
$a_{n+6}=c_{n+5}-b_{n+4}=56x-23y$,
are now with $c_{n+6}=144x-59y=2a_{n+6}+b_{n+4}$:
$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
b_{n+3}&b_{n+4}&b_{n+5}&c_{n+6}-b_{n+5}&c_{n+6}-b_{n+4}=2a_{n+6}\\\hline
17x-7y&32x-13y&44x-18y&100x-41y&112x-46y
\end{array}.$$
We verify that $a_{n+6}=2b_{n+5}-b_{n+4}$, $c_{n+6}-b_{n+5}=3b_{n+5}-b_{n+4}$,
$4b_{n+5}-b_{n+4}=144x-59y=c_{n+6}$, that
$b_{n+5}>b_{n+4}>b_{n+3}$, $b_{n+5}<2b_{n+4}$, that
$b_{n+4}-b_{n+3}=15x-6y$ is between
$b_{n+2}=10x-4y$ and $b_{n+3}$ and that $b_{n+5}-b_{n+4}=12x-5y$ also is
between $b_{n+2}$ and $b_{n+3}$.
Therefore with $n'=n+6$ at the place of $n$ and $x'=b_{n+5}$, $y'=b_{n+4}$
at the place of $x=b_{n-1},y=b_{n-2}$, respectively, we have the same situation
as before the first step.
This finally completes the recursion.

By induction, these 6 steps are repeated infinitely often and determine
the whole sequences $a_k,b_k,c_k$.
In order to deduce the recursive relations $x_{k+12}=31x_{k+6}-4x_k$
for these sequences, we first introduce the vectors
$v_k=(b_{6k},b_{6k-1})^T$, $k=1,2,3,...$. Then $v_1=(b_6,b_5)^T$ and
if $v_k=(x,y)^T$ then $v_{k+1}=(x',y')^T=(44x-18y,32x-13y)^T=A(x,y)^T=Av_k$
with the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}44&-18\\32&-13\end{pmatrix}.$$
Its characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-31\lambda+4$.
By the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, we conclude that $A^2-31A+4I=0$.
Applying this to $v_k$ yields
$v_{k+2}=31v_{k+1}-4v_k$, which means that
$b_{6k+12}=31b_{6k+6}-4b_{6k}$ and $b_{6k+11}=31b_{6k+5}-4b_{6k-1}$
for all $k=1,2,...$.

If we put $x=b_{6k}$, $x'=b_{6k+6}$, $x''=b_{6k+12}$ we have
$x''=31x'-4x$ and similarly for $y=b_{6k-1}$, $y'=b_{6k+5}$, $y''=b_{6k+11}$,
we have $y''=31y'-4y$. Now, as shown in the six steps, for every
$j\in\{1,2,3,4\}$,
the quantity $b_{6k+j}$, $b_{6k+6+j}$, $b_{6k+12+j}$ is a linear combination
of $(x,y)$, $(x',y')$, $(x'',y'')$, respectively, and the coefficients
are the same in the three cases. This implies that we also have
$b_{6k+12+j}=31b_{6k+6+j}-4b_{6k+j}$ for $j=1,2,3,4$
In the same way, the six steps show that for each $j\in\{0,\ldots,5\}$,
$a_{6k+j}$ is a linear combination of  $b_{6k}$ and $b_{6k-1}$ for every $k$
with coefficients independent of $k$.
This implies that also $a_{m+12}=31a_{m+6}-4a_{m}$ for all $m\geq6$.
For the remaining $m=1,...,5$, the relation is shown by a calculating up
to $n=17$. For the sequence $c_m$, we proceed in the same way. This completes the treatment of the last example.

V. An open question for me is whether for all initial conditions,
$a_n$ satisfies a certain recursion
for sufficiently large $n$ and whether it is always one of the
two in the examples of the question. In numerous examples I tried, always one of the two known recursions occurred. Any reports of initial conditions not leading to one of the two recursions is welcome!

Observe that the largest root of $\lambda^{12}-31\lambda^6+4=0$ is $\lambda_b=1.77...$ and therefore slightly smaller than the largest root $\lambda_a=1.80...$ of $\lambda^3-\lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0$. The growth of $a_n$ is therefore not as fast in the last example as in the other ones.

The steps in all the examples also show that the set $B^{(n)}$ of numbers below $a_0+\cdots+a_n$ that cannot be written as sums of distinct elements of $\{a_0,...a_n\}$ has a number of elements of the order $2n$. This is much less than the number of numbers that can be written as such sums which is of the order $\lambda_a^n$ or $\lambda_b^n$ in examples 1-5 or example 6, respectively.

Comment: I appreciate you for your very informative answer! But could you provide a little more detail why $d_{n_0+2}>d_{n_0+1}>d_{n_0}$?

Comment: @dodicta No problem. The reason is that $d_n$ is a solution of the recursion and we have the inequalities in the table for  three subsequent $n$.

Comment: Very impressive.